# WebResponse dynamically 'sometimes' crash

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have a **foreach** with an **"If"** and when the condition is true, I do a WebResponse to post my item in a server.

Sometimes the code run for two o more items but other times crashes with the following error:

The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

The code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

                string authInfo = "admin:geoserver";
                string address = "http://xxxxxxxx:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/";
                client.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo));



                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address);

                request.ContentType = "text/xml";
                request.Method = "POST";

                request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo));

                byte[] bret = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("<workspace><name>" + nameWS + "</name></workspace>");



                Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
                reqstr.Write(bret, 0, bret.Length);
                reqstr.Close();


                try
                {
                    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                    response.Close();

                }
```

My Environment is C# Visual Studio 2010

Comment: It looks like this code is running on a machine that is behind a proxy server that requires authentication in order to access this resource. Depending on the proxy server type and the authentication scheme it requires there might be different ways to solve the issue.

Comment: Are you an authorized personnel to use the response from the site u r using.. ??

Comment: Because it might be problem from the site, to protect from DOS attack.

Answer (score 0):

how often do you call this? as others have suggested it could be that the server is protected from DOS and your requests are seen like that. It's also valuable to dispose immediately all disposable objects with a using block for example. we had some issues once while leaving too many connections open to our web server, internally in our network. You could adjust your code to look like this:

```
using(var client = new WebClient())
{
    string authInfo = "admin:geoserver";
    string address = "http://xxxxxxxx:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/";
    client.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo));

    var request = WebRequest.Create(address);

    request.ContentType = "text/xml";
    request.Method = "POST";

    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo));

    byte[] bret = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("<workspace><name>" + nameWS + "</name></workspace>");

    using (var reqstr = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        reqstr.Write(bret, 0, bret.Length);
    }

    try
    {
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            // your code here...
        }

    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
    }
}
```